# Android, Foursquare and the & #8212; character

Tags: java, android, unicode, utf-8, foursquare

When sending the `&#8212;` to foursquare, it appears as ? on their site instead of —, the long dash. It appears fine within the Android app (I'm displaying it using \u2014), but not on the foursquare website. I know the site can handle the symbol as I can add it when making edits on the site. In fact the site seems to rendering it using the \u2014. So something is happening from the time it is sent to the server and then rendered back on the page. Any help is much appreciated.

I add the dash using:

```
mDetailPlaceholder.setText("\u2014 at " + mVenueName);
```

Then I pass the string to the foursquare API like so:

```
String shout = mDetailText.getText().toString() + " " + mDetailPlaceholder.getText().toString();
```

It may be that the unicode is being lost when using the toString() and so the raw dash is sent.

Comment: So far I've tried: adding `\u2014` to the string directly. I've also tried saving the file as utf-8 and adding the — directly to the string. Still does not render properly on foursquare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set encoding style to utf-8 before sending to foursquare server:

```
    req.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));
```

... where req is an HttpPost object, and params is a List object.